# Corrección de archivo htaccess

Tags: php

Este es mi archivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Añade siempre una / al final de la url, excepto cuando la extensión acaba en .php. Por otro lado, quiero evitar que aparezca .php (algo que no debe suceder) y quiero añadir siempre una barra al final (/). Ejemplo:
http://localhost/panel.php -> http://localhost/panel/

La respuesta de este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625985/htaccess-remove-php-and-add-trailing-slash) me vale, pero tiene una vulnerabilidad, y es que si el usuario añade un número o un valor cualquiera al final de la url después de la barra se producen muchas redirecciones. Su respuesta es lo que busco pero no se cómo evitar ese problema

Answer (score 0):

Yo puedo ayudar con lo de las extensiones. Este código jamás me ha fallado para quitar las extensiones.

```
# Quitar extensión de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# END Quitar extensión de las URL
```

Para la barra puedes probar con el siguiente código pero no estoy seguro si es lo que buscas.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Lo que no me queda claro es porque quieres esa barra?? Si es por manejo de urls y/o variables, lo puedes manejar en código... Si puedes comentar sobre ello, sería excelente.